# ATLAS control reverse engineer on ROS-Gazebo

Tags: control, ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, My name is Diego Cifuentes and I am working on the implementation of a control system for stability in biped robots, currently. I am using the platform ROS (Robot Operating System) and the simulator Gazebo. Could someone advise me on some files in programming ROS. I need to reverse engineer the file extension (. Launch) static and dynamic control of the ATLAS platform (biped robot). Help me, please. Any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60577/atlas-control-reverse-engineer-on-ros-gazebo/) by [DieGo_Cif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4369/diego_cif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your question is extremely vague and hence it is hard to give you an/any answer.

Both ROS and Gazebo offer a lot of on-line documentation and tutorials ([ROS wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki), [Gazebo wiki](http://gazebosim.org/wiki)). I suggest you start there in order to learn the basics of both tools. This shouldn't take you too long.

Afterwards, feel free to use ROS and [Gazebo Answers](http://answers.gazebosim.org/) for further help. But please remember to ask specific questions, then it is more likely you will get an answer.

Good luck!

PS: Look at [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch#The_Launch_File) for a roslaunch-quickstart (uses .launch files). However, I still recommend to go through the other tutorials as well.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1